# "В одного человека" или "в один человек"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, числительные

*село/деревня с населением...*

Как правильно?

Comment: Артё-ом... Вечно ты *чегой-то-нибудь* да изыщешь!

Comment: Конечно, "в один человек". "В два человека" или "в двух человек"?

Comment: Ахахах, Рим!))) Oleedd прав?

Comment: Если это не убедило, то вот: *с населением в двадцати одного человека*.

Comment: Это убеждает, но хочется какого-то рассуждения на эту тему или ссылки на такое уже имеющееся.

Comment: @oleedd Сначала вы пишете *конечно, "в один человек"*. Потом — *с населением в двадцати одного человека*. Так как же все-таки надо?

Comment: В теле вопроса надо иметь полную фразу, где можно было бы видеть связь и согласование слов. Желать «рассуждения на тему» можно, но хорошо бы и проблему обозначить.

Comment: @shampar: меня интересуют все фразы, в которых может говориться о населённых пунктах, где живёт один человек. Это может быть и посёлок, и другие поселения. Также интересует и склонение других числительных в словосочетании "население в N человек(а)". Вроде бы не говорят "...в семи человек", значит, не говорят и "в двух человек" и, стало быть, и "в одного человека" тоже не говорят. Но нет полной уверенности, что всё так однозначно, и ответа на вопрос, почему так.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова: если я правильно понял, oleedd привёл пример с 21 человеком как явно ошибочный, типа "так же не скажешь".

Comment: В одного человека может войти литр кваса (пример).

Comment: Если я правильно понял, приведённый пример с 21, заменив **это нечто** , смог бы как-то вывести «рассуждения» из тупика, т. к. в одиночку никто **населять** не способен, хоть он тресни.

Comment: @shampar: нет, shampar, бывают населённые пункты, где живёт один человек, например село Амузги.

Comment: не «в», а «из».

Comment: Бывает, и он — житель, поселенец, но не население.

Comment: Ну хорошо, если так нельзя сказать в случае с одним человеком, давайте рассмотрим цифру "три".

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова: так как правильно-то, Рим?

Answer (score 0):

Села в одного человека быть не может. Не может один человек образовать село. В смысле одним только собой.
Село в одного человека говорит о том, что село ранее было, но сейчас опустело, остался лишь один человек.

Comment: Конечно опустело! И как в таком случае правильно будет сказать?